# How to combine recommended lists produced by two different models?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, recommender-system

Suppose there are two algorithms that I use to generate recommendations for a user, the first one producing list A, the second one producing list B, both of length $k$. Is there a clever way of combining the two lists (to create a hybrid approach, so to say) into a final list C of the same length as A and B? I suppose that some scoring could be possible, but I'm not sure what to base the scores on.

Another idea I had is the following: I have access to embedding vectors of items from both lists (A and B), so to extract the final list C I would look at the embedding and extract the items that are closest to the means of $k$ clusters found in the embedding space. Do you think it's a good idea? How would you utilize the items' embedding vectors?

Of course, a link to general literature address the above described issue is highly welcome.

Comment: @Kasra Manshaei Maybe you could help

Comment: The simple idea is to average the ranks: if for an item x method A gives rank $r_A$ and method B gives rank $r_B$, assign rank $(r_A+r_B)/2$. Do this for every item (or every item in the top N for any method), then reorder the items by the new rank.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks! But what about the case when there are no common items between the two recommended list?

Comment: In this case you can't do anything at all, it's as if the 2 systems work with different input data.

Comment: @Erwan I have access to item embeddings of both sets, so certainly some kind of clever combination is possible, don't you think?